# Get attribute of bundle items

Tags: attributes, bundle, items

When a bundle product is shown, i need to load a specific attribute of the asigned bundle items (which are simple products of course).

The attributes must be loaded in the view.phtml file located in `/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/product/`

My magento version is 1.9.2 CE, thanks for your help.

**Edit:**

Ok let me be more specific. I have a bundle product which consists of serveral simple products. Some of these simple products have an attribute called "length".

I need to calculate the length of the bundle product by adding all the lengths of the assigned simple products.
Can anyone tell me please how this can be done?

Comment: how to you add the attribute value while adding the product in admin panel?

Comment: The simple products contain the attribute value. I need to get these values.

Comment: does the attribute is created by you self?
If yes you can use this code $_product->getMerchant();
i guess your attribute as "merchant".If this is retrieve a value for you let me know to post ass an Answer.

Comment: Yes, but i need to get the attribute of the simple products, not the bundle one.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found out myself.
I needed to change the select.phtml (and also checkbox.phtml, because i am using dropdowns AND checkboxes)

The files are located in:
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/select.phtml

To get the attribute "my_length" i just added the following code:

`$product_id = $_selection->getId(); //gets the product id of the option
$_resource = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->getResource();
$my_length = $_resource->getAttributeRawValue($product_id, 'my_length', Mage::app()->getStore()); //gets the attribute value
        if (!my_length) //not really sure if this is needed
            $my_length=0; ?>`

Then i just echoed the length in the class:
`<input type="hidden" name="bundle_option[getId() ?>]" value="getSelectionId() ?>" class="mylength<?php echo $my_length; ?>" />`

The rest was done with javascript.

It can be necessary to add the code above more than once, depending on the original phtml file. For example in select.phtml is:
`if ($this->_showSingle()):`
.... this is done when there is only one option.
`else`
.... this is done when there are more than one option

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve any attribute from the view page by writing this code.

```
$_product->getAttribute();
```

Since the attribute created by you is "**Attribute**".

Ex Your Attribute is **"merchant"** you can get the value by calling this

```
$_product->getMerchant();
```

Answer (score 0):

First need to find out simple product id's of bundle item. Then load the product from the id and then call the attribute value.

```
//here $bundle is an object of bundle item
$bundle_ids = $bundle->getTypeInstance(true)->getChildrenIds($bundle->getId(), false);

$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

$simple_products = $model->getCollection()
                   ->addAttributeToSelect('your_attribute') //change your attribute id/name
                   ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $bundle_ids));

foreach($simple_products as $simple){
    echo $simple->getAttributeText('your_attribute')."<br>";
    //or do other stuff
}
```

Hope this helps.